# How to add folium's BoatMarker with other layers in python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, leaflet, folium

I am trying to create a map with layer controls.
Under FeatureGroup layer

1. hot_spot_layer - Markers with Marker Clusters
2. Route layer - Using Antpath plotting the route

After this I am trying to plot Boatmarker at the end of the route.
Without Boatmarker the map is rendering as expected, but when I add the boatmarker plugin to the base map object, the map is not rendering anything.

```
import folium 
from folium import plugins

# Creating Map Object
mapObj = folium.Map(location = [1.27,103.78],tiles='OpenStreetMap',
                 zoom_start =4)

# Place Markers for hotspots
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="All Layers") #Creating feature group
mapObj.add_child(fg) #Adding feature group to based map object

# adding Hotspots as subgroup of feature group
hot_spot_layer = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg,name="Hotspots")

#Creating markercluster for hotspots 
marker_cluster = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(hot_spot_layer) 

#Adding a marker
folium.Marker(location= [1.3,143.12],
                icon=folium.Icon(color='brown', icon='anchor', 
prefix='fa')).add_to(marker_cluster) # Adding it to the marker cluster
mapObj.add_child(hot_spot_layer) # Adding to the basemap object

#Route path
# Adding "Routes" as a subgroup of feature group
route_layer = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg,name="Routes") 
corr_list = [[-4.14,116.25], [-7.28,117.78]] # Route Coordinates
plugins.AntPath(corr_list).add_to(route_layer) # Adding it to route layer
mapObj.add_child(route_layer) # Adding to the basemap object
#### Upto this point no issue ####

# Some issue when I try to add Boatmarker 
# If I execute the below commented line my map is not rendering with markers & route path

# Adding to the basemap object , please uncomment to see the map is not rendering

#folium.plugins.BoatMarker(location=(-7.14,116.25),heading=-20).add_to(mapObj) 

folium.LayerControl(collapsed=True).add_to(mapObj) #Assigning layer control
mapObj.save('test.html')   # html generation
```

[Without Boatmarker - No issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzebR.png)

[With Boatmarker, the map is not rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwc22.png)

I am very new to folium, so I know my code may be kind of rusty.

Comment: I'm also new to folium. I looked into this for some hours now, and I'm not sure why the BoatMarker causes nothing to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out. I am assuming some issue with the layer control/adding marker objects to Featurelayers. I am unable to resolve it. I used circle marker instead of Boatmarker and it works.

Comment: Yes, I also was suspecting something like this. It's too bad that it doesn't work "out of the box". Maybe some expert in folium or Python could look through the Boatmarker script and explain where it all goes wrong. Maybe it would even be possible to contribute to a better implementation of the plugin. Hope someone comes to the rescue here :-)